# Qt qml - run a line without any conditions (while(true))

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am a noob in qml. I am using the CircularGauge class and I want to constantly update the value. The currently code I found online only changes the value if a key is pressed (line 7). However, I want the value to be updated no matter what( similar to while(true) in c++. In line 7, dashboard is a class defined in C++ and the class member function will grab a value from hardwares.

```
CircularGauge {
    scale : 0.7
    value: accelerating ? maximumValue : 0
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    property bool accelerating: false
    Keys.onPressed: {
         value = Dashboard.getSpeed();
    }
}
```

Still no luck. The updated code is:

```
Window {    
   x: 100 
   y: 100
   width: 190 
   height: 190
   visible: true
   MouseArea {
      anchors.fill: parent
      onClicked: {
            Qt.quit();
      }
   }

CircularGauge {
    scale : 0.7
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    Timer {
        interval: 50
        running: true
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: value = Dashboard.getSpeed()
    }
    Component.onCompleted: forceActiveFocus()
    Behavior on value {
        NumberAnimation {
            duration: 100
        }
    }
}
```

}

Solved:

```
Window {    
x: 100 
y: 100
width: 190 
height: 190
visible: true
CircularGauge {
scale : 0.7
anchors.centerIn: parent
id: dashboard
Timer {
    interval: 40
    running: true
    repeat: true
    onTriggered: dashboard.value = Dashboard.getSpeed()
}
}
}
```

Comment: Does `onValueChanged: value = 0` work?

Comment: I tired that but it didn't work. Maybe I put it in a wrong place? Which line should I put it?  Appreciated.

Comment: Just somewhere in `CircularGauge`, for example above `scale: 0.7`. Note that the order of lines doesn't matter in QML.

Comment: @m7913d now the value is reset to zero after I release a key, but I still need to press a key for the value to be constantly update :( I have change the word "reset" to "update" in the post. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: As what you posted in the section *solved* is exactly what proposed in *dtech*s answer, it is good practice on this site to mark the correct (and best) answer as accepted. See [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the helppage describing what to do when someone provides an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I just started to used this forum. Please let me know if there is more things I have to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a [`Timer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-timer.html) element to continuously execute code at a specific interval?

```
Timer {
    interval: 100
    running: true
    repeat: true
    onTriggered: doYourStuff()
}
```

You definitely don't want anything like `while(true)` (unless you have a manual exit point) as that will block the thread and as a result your application will effectively hang.

Also consider that the moment you `value = something`, you will break the existing binding for `value` that you have.

Try something like this:

```
CircularGauge {
  scale : 0.7
  anchors.centerIn: parent
  Timer {
    interval: 100
    running: true
    repeat: true
    onTriggered: value = value ? 0 : Dashboard.getSpeed()
  }
}
```

What it will do is every 100 milliseconds it will set value to either 0 if current value is not 0, or to `Dashboard.getSpeed()`.

OK, you made another change, if all you want to do is update the value continuously, then all you need for the timer trigger handler is:

```
onTriggered: value = Dashboard.getSpeed()
```

But an even more correct design would be to have a `speed` `Q_PROPERTY` in your `Dashboard` class, with implemented notifications on value change, then all you need to do in QML is this:

```
CircularGauge {
  value: Dashboard.speed
}
```

And ideally, the update frequency of the dashboard can be set, and it will still use a timer, but using the `QTimer` C++ class.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried that but the behavior did not changed. Maybe I put these lines in a wrong place? Which line should I put it?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Things make more sense now. However, the current code is still not working (updated in the porst) :( . I will try the Q_PROPTY next.

Comment: The code should work, it is simple and straightforward, if it doesn't work the blame lies with your `Dashboard` class.

Comment: understood. I will look it up

Comment: I think its because in the Dashboard class I used QTimer to update a OpenGL scene

Comment: I think you should familiarize yourself with the core concepts of QML (especially what it means to work with a *declarative language*) and with model-view-something-architectures. Further keep in mind that you should not write your own render loop if unless your motto is "*no risk no fun"* or you are very very experienced with Qt/QML and have some definitve reasons for it. (The documentation strongly discourages it, I just can't find the page OTG). And then go with *dtech*s latter solution with the `Q_PROPERTY`.